# Is $sort always required after a $project and $match in Mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a working aggregation call that performs a $project, $match and $sort (by _id) which works perfectly fine.

In order to optimize my app, I tried dropping the $sort part at the end because I'm actually sorting by a datetime string in my php app after the cursor function is returned. Hence why I no longer wish to sort by _id.

However, when I remove this part of the pipeline, it returns no data. Is this a required part of my call?

```
  $pipeline = [
    ['$project' => [
      'date' => '$date',
      'time' => '$time',
      'datetime' => '$datetime',
      'dev_id' => '$dev_id'
      ],
    ],
    ['$match' => [
      'dev_id' => ['$in' => $deviceIdArray],
      'datetime' => ['$gte' => $this->dateFrom, '$lte' => $this->dateTo]],
    ],
    ['$sort' => ['_id' => -1],
    ],
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are doing `project` then doing `match`, so you are not getting any result as output.

Try the code below:-

```
 $pipeline = [
 ['$match' => [
  'dev_id' => ['$in' => $deviceIdArray],
  'datetime' => ['$gte' => $this->dateFrom, '$lte' => $this->dateTo]],
]
['$project' => [
  'date' => '$date',
  'time' => '$time',
  'datetime' => '$datetime',
  'dev_id' => '$dev_id'
  ],
]
];
```